# Vim netrw_list_hide doesn't behave like a normal regexp

Tags: regex, vim, netrw

I'm trying to hide Python's `__pycache__` directories in Vim's Netrw by setting:

```
:let g:netrw_list_hide = '^__pycache__$'
```

The value of this variable is supposed to be a regexp, yet the above pattern doesn't hide the `__pycache__` directories. Setting it to the more simple:

```
:let g:netrw_list_hide = '__pycache__'
```

Does work, but then it over-matches to any path that contains this substring anywhere, so for example `__pycache__foo` will be ignored too.

Any idea why the first matching pattern doesn't work?

Comment: Check other options that may affect the functionality. Try commenting out `let g:netrw_liststyle = 1` line (if you have it).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I tried that, didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

Try :let g:netrw_list_hide = '__pycache__/'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netrw_gitignore#Hide()` function, which will hide all files inside your .gitignore file.

Here is how I have used the function with `g:netrw_list_hide` in my vimrc.

```
 let g:netrw_list_hide = netrw_gitignore#Hide()
```

You may have to reload your vim or source your config for this to work.

For more info about `netrw_list_hide` and `netrw_gitignore` just type

`:h netrw_list_hide` and
`:h netrw_gitignore`

in vim command line mode to see the manual

Cheers